# Why h2::after element comes right below main h2 element with margin-bottom?

Tags: html, css

I just dont get it why margin-bottom in main h2 element doesnt have impact on its "::after" element, because these are defined as block elements and one margin should be enough in order to have distance between them. Even though "h2::after" element has 0 margin of top and bottom, I think because of bottom margin of h2 it should provide 40px of distance but I dont know why they just stick

```
<html lang='en>'>
        <body>
            <h2>Main h2 heading</h2>
                <style>
                    h2 {
                        content: "main h2";
                        font-size: 180%;
                        margin-bottom: 40px;
                        word-spacing: 2px;
                        text-align: center;
                        color: #000;
                    
                    }
                
                    h2::after {
                        display: block;
                        background-color: #4cd137;
                        height: 5px;
                        width: 250px;
                        content: " ";
                        margin: 0 auto;

                    }
             
               </style>
        </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It considers `h2` and `h2::after` as a single element. So adding `margin-bottom` to `h2` won't make any difference. Instead, you can add `margin-top` to the after element to get some spacing between it.

```css
h2 {
  content: "main h2";
  font-size: 180%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
                
h2::after {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4cd137;
  height: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  content: " ";
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:40px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Main h2 heading</h2>
```

Comment: thanks I didnt know they were considered like single element actually now it makes sense

Comment: @ElchinB. no, they are not singe element. the :after element is inside h2 so will not get affected by the margin of its container

Answer (score 0):

**Margin** properties are used to create space around elements, outside of any defined borders not for inner elements... ***check below 2 methods for you solutions***

```css
h2, h3 {
  content: "main h2";
  font-size: 180%;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin:auto;
}

h2::after {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4cd137;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  content: " ";
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

h3::after {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4cd137;
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  content: " ";
  margin: 40px auto 0;
}


p{text-align: center;}
```

```html
<p>Done with Position</p>
<h2>Main h2 heading</h2>
<br><br><br><br>
<p>Done with Margin</p>
<h3>Main h3 heading</h3>
```

Hope it works :)